# mock method invocation returns null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net

I have the following method which scrubs the incomplete address. For Eg: Say AddressLine1="800 Wash s st" then it returns "800 Washington s st".
For this method, I'm using a `AddressScrubbingApi` via the `ApiClientHelper`. Hence in my current code, I have the dependency of `ApiClientHelper`.

```
public async Task<PartyAddress> ScrubAddress(PartyAddress addressToBeScrubbed)
{
if (_baseApiClient == null)
{
 SetApiClient(new BaseApiClient());
}
AddressScrubbingRequest addressObject = BuildRequestObject(addressToBeScrubbed);
string path = "/v1/addresses/actions/scrub";
//this is the baseApiClient that is to be injected as mock in unit test
var scrubbedAddress = await _baseApiClient.CallPostApiAsync<AddressScrubbingResponse>(AddressScrubbingApiKey, path, addressObject);
    if (scrubbedAddress.Status == ValidationStatus.HighProbabilityMatch.ToString())
     {
      addressToBeScrubbed.Addr1 = scrubbedAddress.Primary;
      addressToBeScrubbed.Addr2 = scrubbedAddress.Secondary;        
      addressToBeScrubbed.StreetNumber = scrubbedAddress.HouseNumber;
      addressToBeScrubbed.City = scrubbedAddress.City;
      addressToBeScrubbed.StateProv = StateCode.GetId(scrubbedAddress.State).HasValue ? AcordConversionHelper.CreateCodeValue(scrubbedAddress.State, StateCode.GetId(scrubbedAddress.State)) : AcordConversionHelper.CreateCodeValue(null, null);
      addressToBeScrubbed.PostalCode = scrubbedAddress.Zip5;
      addressToBeScrubbed.ZipExtension = scrubbedAddress.Zip4;
      addressToBeScrubbed.StreetName = scrubbedAddress.Name;
     //some more fields here
     addressToBeScrubbed.SuccessfullyScrubbedDtTm = System.DateTime.Now;
     }
     else if (scrubbedAddress.Status == ValidationStatus.MultipleMatches.ToString() || scrubbedAddress.Status == ValidationStatus.LowProbabilityMatch.ToString())
     {
      addressToBeScrubbed.StreetName = scrubbedAddress.Name;
      //partyAddress.Address.StreetType = scrubbedAddress.StreetTypeDesignator;
      //PreDirection=scrubbedAddress.PreDirection;
      //PostDirection=scrubbedAddress.PostDirection;
      addressToBeScrubbed.SuccessfullyScrubbedDtTm = System.DateTime.Now;
      }
   return addressToBeScrubbed;
}
```

Here is the unit test I'm have tried so far

```
public static async Task ConvertFromAcordScrubAddressTest()
{
TestHelper.InitializeAcordConversionMetadata();
ConvertFromAcord.PartyConversion partyConversion = new ConvertFromAcord.PartyConversion();
Address address = TestHelper.SetupPartyAddress();
var requestAddress = TestHelper.SetupRequestAddress(address);
var mock = new Mock<IBaseApiClient>();
partyConversion.SetApiClient(mock.Object);
string path = "/v1/addresses/actions/scrub";
mock.Setup(m => m.CallPostApiAsync<AddressScrubbingResponse>(AddressScrubbingApiKey, path, requestAddress))
                .ReturnsAsync(new AddressScrubbingResponse
                {
                    Status = "MultipleMatches",
                    Message = "Multiple matches were found for the address you entered.  Normally this is a result of not including East, West, North, or South in the address line.",
                    IsPhysicalMatch = false,
                    Primary = "800 N WASHINGTON ST",
                    Secondary = string.Empty,
                    City = "VAN WERT",
                    State = "OH",
                    Zip5 = "45891",
                    Zip4 = "1269",
                    HouseNumber = "800",
                    PostDirection = string.Empty,
                    Name = "Washington",
                    StreetTypeDesignator = "St",
                    PreDirection = "N",
                    PoBoxNumber = string.Empty,
                    UnitTypeDesignator = string.Empty,
                    UnitNumber = string.Empty,
                    PrivateMailBox = string.Empty
                });
var scrubbedAddress=await  partyConversion.ScrubAddress(address);

 // Assert.PropertyChanged(address, nameof(address.Addr1), t=>t.partyConversion.ScrubAddress(address));
// this is to test whether Addr1 property is set when a call to the partyConversion.ScrubAddress(address); is made in above.
}
```

My questions as follows

1. When my mock is passed, in the `partyConversion.ScrubAddress()` method, it returns null. So the line after that is throwing Object reference null exception.
   I'm I creating the mock in wrong way?
2. How do I test this method for checking property changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems that the passed mocked `requestAddress` is not **equal** than created addressObject via code `AddressScrubbingRequest addressObject = BuildRequestObject(addressToBeScrubbed);`

You can define that last parameter as `It.IsAny<AddressScrubbingRequest>()` during the `Setup` in that case, your mock method will be invoked.

```
mock.Setup(m => m.CallPostApiAsync<AddressScrubbingResponse>
                 (AddressScrubbingApiKey, path, It.IsAny<AddressScrubbingRequest>()))
```